# how to paste event's profile picture using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, events

I would like to generate events automatically for subscribers of my website.  This is working properly but I'm unable to paste the event's profile picture

For creating event(working properly):

```
$access_token = 'app_access_token';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/app_id/events";
$postdata = "access_token=$access_token&name=$name&start_time=$start_time&end_time=$end_time&description=$description&privacy=$privacy&location=$location&picture=$picture_source";             
$event_code = curl_sending_newsfeed_facebook($url, $postdata);
```

For pasting a picture

```
$picture_source = "pic_source.jpg";             
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/event_id/picture?source=$picture_source&access_token=$access_token";
$postdata = "";
$pic_code = curl_sending_newsfeed_facebook($url, $postdata);
```

Comment: I guess you mean posting, not “pasting”? And did you even have a look at the docs on how to upload photos? Just giving a file name in the source parameter is definitively _not_ how it works. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#photos

Comment: i want to print The event's profile picture.

Comment: ya i have thoroughly check the link you sent me,,,,,,but i cant find my mistake

Comment: When using the `source` parameter, the photo data has to be encoded corresponding to the type `multipart/form-data` – same as if it was actually an HTTP file upload through a browser.